# Выводить значения TV параметров всех дочерних ресурсов

Tags: modx, pdo, pdotools, pdoresourse, pdofield

У меня есть такое дерево ресурсов (в скобках их id)

```html
-Автомобили
--Легковые(7)
---BMD(8)
---AUDI(9)
--Грузовые
---Ваз
```

все (списком) эти параметры на родителе с ID 7 и на его дочерних ресурсах.

Пытаюсь делать так, но ничего должного не получается:

Код:

```html
[[pdoResources?
&parent=`7` 
&depth=`0`
&tpl=`priceblock`
&includeTVs=`1` 
&processTVs=`1`
]]
```

tpl:

```html
[[*pricerub]]
```

Что я делаю не так? Выводятся только единичные значения, но не всех ресурсов..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вместо **&parent=`7`** указать **&parents=`7`**

Comment: Точно, спасибо )